# Statistical significance of the event argument in Survival function in R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have created a Cox Regression model for Survival Analysis on a churn dataset.Now I am confused at two points:

1. When I write `Surv(time,status)` as the survival object and commit the cox regression, I get a very bad survival curve which does not reach the survival probability of `0.5`
2. When I write `Surv(time,status==0)` as the survival object and commit the cox regression,I get a decent survival curve which reaches the almost `0` probability mark at the end of the time duration of the observation.

The `time` parameter in my dataset has a peculiar anomaly. Those with `status==0` have a very high `time` value and those with `status==1` have a very low `time` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statistical significance is like this :

```
fit1<- Surv(time,event)
df1<-as.data.frame.character(fit1)
```

gives a result where all the individuals for whom `status == 1` are considered censored i.e their times will be designated as `2+,3+` etc. and those whose `status==0`, their status will be considered dead after their respective time given in the time column, i.e their times will be given as `13,10,15` etc. The moot point is those who are alive will be considered dead after their respective times and those who are alive will be considered dead after their respective times.